# Jenkins triggers jobs without git changes

Tags: git, jenkins, docker

We have a jenkins server running that builds the respective jobs on a docker container using the [docker jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin):

Each job checks every N minutes whether changes on git have been made. In case of any change a docker container is created and the project is successfully build on that container. Finally, after building, the docker container is going to shutdown.

*The problem*:
Jenkins triggers all N minutes a new build *without any changes on git*. The problem might be that there are no workspaces available to check for changes since the docker container is not available anymore.

Any idea how to solve that problem?

Edit: Our jenkins server isn't accessible from public net.

Edit: Workaround: Create a new job that definitely clone the project into 
a workspace (on the jenkins master) and trigger some children jobs in case on a change. The difference here is that master keeps the workspace and is therefore able to check for differences whereas the workspace of the docker container is deleted once the container is closed.

Answer (score 0):

why to check for every N minutes for git changes.
the Best thing is to make Jenkins build after every git change.
1. check poll scm option, but do not enter anything in schedule.[image] 
2. Now go to git repository folder and go into hooks folder, there you will find hooks samples, use post-receive.sample, rename it to post-receive , make it as executable, then in the  file write

```
#!/bin/bash

curl http://yourserver/jenkins/git/notifyCommit?url=<URL of the Git repository
```

Then save it. Now Jenkins build after every Git change.

Comment: Unfortunately, our server isn't accessible our the public net such that we er unable to trigger a job from outside. But, of course, you are completely right.

Comment: you can configure a dynamic ddns address with a no-ip like services and use port forwarding and can completely use it as a cloud server.

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is that only SSH is publicly available.